# How do we know that the suprnova worker is producing value?

Tags: mining-pools, bitcoin-cash

I followed [this tutorial](https://steemit.com/dtube/@danieleborrello/0uevqxe3) to attempt to mine bitcoin cash on https://bcc.suprnova.cc/.  It seems to be working.  My terminal prints out stuff like this:

```
[2017-11-11 14:47:51] Stratum requested work restart
[2017-11-11 14:47:51] thread 1: 85454192 hashes, 3397 khash/s
[2017-11-11 14:47:51] thread 4: 92140688 hashes, 3351 khash/s
[2017-11-11 14:47:51] thread 6: 80503816 hashes, 3464 khash/s
[2017-11-11 14:47:51] thread 3: 84560368 hashes, 3376 khash/s
```

But if I look at the Dashboard and scroll down to Worker Information it says `No Active Workers`.  So how do we know that https://bcc.suprnova.cc/ is actually giving us credit for running the worker?

There's also an earnings link in the side panel and after running the miner for a day, the earning table is showing all 0s.  So it appears that after one day of running the miner nothing has been accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mining so slowly that the mining pool thinks you are not mining.

You can't mine sha-256 coins with CPU. You are several hardware generations too late.

CPUs had to give up bitcoin mining in 2011 when GPUs took over completely. Then came FPGAs which made life hard on GPU miners. Finally in 2013 the ASICs arrived which made GPU and FPGA mining completely pointless. Now in 2017 this is old news and sha-256 mining has been ASIC-only for years.

Just like with BTC, BCH (BCC) is also mined with ASICs.

Why do people give up on old and inefficient ways of mining:

1. It would take several hundred years before you have earned the minimum amount to cash out from the pool. Not only is this tiny amount not worth 5 minutes of your time - you are not going to live long enough to cash it out.
2. If you lived for 1000 years and mined the whole time, earning 1 US dollar worth of BTC or BCH/BCC, you would have paid a million dollars in electricity to get there. How would it make sense to do so?

Back in 2009 some people would mine 50 bitcoins per day with the CPU of an old laptop. Unfortunately it is not 2009 anymore. Today you earn zero with CPU.

Comment: Shoot - I was going to setup my old samsung note phone to try to mine a few as well.  Any ideas on how to get back to 2009?

Comment: I'm sure there will be a time machine ICO soon. But I'm not sure if that's a sound investment. :P